# Subtracting unique id rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[image: output]I have a dataset like this, I need help with a code that will calculate difference for each id based on type a

so for id 222, value for type a - type a, value for type b - type a, value for type c - type a.  and this will go for each unique IDs.

```
id   type   value   difference
222   a      10.5
222   b      70.0
222   c      148.5
333   a      40.5
333   b      60.2
333   c      180.5
444   a      60.8
444   b      140.2
444   c      210.5
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: i have not tried any yet, i just can do this in excel

Comment: Can you please include the expected output for the "difference" column? I didn't get the exaplanation and would like to understand what's the output that you expect

Comment: i have an image with output

Answer (score 0):

### Solution with `unstack`

You can start by unstacking on type:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['id','type']).unstack()
```

df2 looks like:

```
        value
type    a   b       c
id          
222    10.5 70.0    148.5
333    40.5 60.2    180.5
444    60.8 140.2   210.5
```

Then we subtract column `a` and stack back into the original shape:

```
df3 = df2.subtract(df2[('value','a')], axis=0).stack().reset_index()
```

`df3` looks like this:

```
    id  type value
0   222 a    0.0
1   222 b    59.5
2   222 c    138.0
3   333 a    0.0
4   333 b    19.7
5   333 c    140.0
6   444 a    0.0
7   444 b    79.4
8   444 c    149.7
```

Then you can stick it back into the original `df`:

```
df['difference'] = df3['value']
```

and `df` now looks like this

```
    id  type value  difference
0   222 a    10.5   0.0
1   222 b    70.0   59.5
2   222 c    148.5  138.0
3   333 a    40.5   0.0
4   333 b    60.2   19.7
5   333 c    180.5  140.0
6   444 a    60.8   0.0
7   444 b    140.2  79.4
8   444 c    210.5  149.7
```

### Solution with `groupby`

```
df['difference'] = df.groupby('id', group_keys = False).apply(lambda g: g - g.set_index('type').loc['a'])['value']
```